# running the ld command through rust only works 50% of the time

Tags: rust, process, linker, command

I'm trying to create a compiler in rust. I'm now at a point where I want to link the outputted object file into an executable with this command `ld test.o -o test`. When I run this command manually in the shell, it always works. Though, when I let rust do it, it sometimes works and sometimes gives this error: `ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address`

It's truly 50/50 and I have no idea what is causing this.

This is how I run the command:

```rust
process::Command::new("ld")
    .arg(format!("{}.o", outputfile))
    .arg("-o")
    .arg(&outputfile)
    .spawn()
    .expect("Failed to link");
```

I've tried to debug this by checking what rust actually runs by printing out the command like this:

```rust
println!(
    "{:?}",
    process::Command::new("ld")
        .arg(format!("{}.o", outputfile))
        .arg("-o")
        .arg(&outputfile)
);
```

This will print out: `"ld" "test.o" "-o" "test"` which I copied directly into my shell which worked without any issue.

It's very weird and I've been trying to fix this for way too long now. Please help if you know what might be causing this.

Edit:
In case there is any extra information you need in order to help, you can find all of the code on my GitHub: https://github.com/sten-code/rlangc
The issue is about the code all the way at the bottom of `main.rs` inside the build function.
Please note that I started learning rust yesterday so the code might suck.

Comment: You might want to add your configuration and environment as well as the complete error message, else we can't really help much. Also where do you run that from? `build.rs`?

Comment: @cafce25 I have a build function inside main.rs, the code is on github: https://github.com/sten-code/rlangc You can find it all the way at the bottom of main.rs

Comment: Do you [`.wait()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.wait) until the [`Child`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html) returned from `spawn` is done with it's work?

Comment: @cafce25 Ah, I just realized that rust runs commands asynchronous so the nasm command that happens right before the linker command was still busy while the linker command was started. The linker relies on the nasm command so thats why it was 50/50. Thank you for your help with this very dumb issue.

Comment: Rust does what you tell it to, `spawn` doesn't wait for it's child to return. You can use [`status`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.status) to wait on the return value, in general, there are several methods that run a `Command` and do different things.

Comment: @cafce25 I used status before that and I got the same problem, just using `.wait()` after the `.expect()` function fixed it.

Comment: Unlikely as `status` *"Executes a command as a child process, **waiting for it to finish and collecting its status**."* you must have hit another problem such as `nasm` not successfully returning which `expect()` will **not** catch, only checking the `ExitStatus` will.

Comment: @cafce25 Now that I think about it, I added the `.status()` to the linker command, not the nasm command which means that it was waiting for the linker command to be done and not the nasm command.

Answer (score 0):

### Fixed Issue

The issue was that I was running a nasm command right before the linker command. The linker relies on the output of the nasm command. **`Command::spawn` in Rust runs commands asynchronous**, so when I was running the linker command there was a 50% chance that the nasm command wasn't done creating the object file resulting it in a crash. Thanks to @cafce25 for pointing this out to me.